# Access Internet on android phone by connecting it to laptop?

Tags: laptop, usb, internet, android, cable-modem

My latop is connected to a wired modem for internet. I want to access internet on my android phone.

Can i do it by connecting my Android to laptop via usb cable and then enabling tethering.

Edit:

Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I forgot to mention: its ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @CharlieRB can you remove 'This question may have an answer here' banner as it is apparent that question has been edited to update the OS.

Comment: I removed my vote and comment related to being a duplicate. If my answer was correct, please select it as being the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Use this without root https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet

Answer (score 1):

You will need do a reverse tether. As far as I know, the phone must be rooted for this to be done.

Here are instructions at XDA Developers - 
[HOWTO: Ubuntu USB reverse tethering](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1212548)

Comment: If you are reading this in 2016, this no longer works for android v5 and above

Answer (score 1):

Here's the closest to a "one-click" solution that I got to.

**Prerequisites**

- Rooted Android device
- Root access on the PC
- [ADB](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) installed on the PC (`apt-get install android-tools-adb` on Debian-based distros)
- [USB Debugging enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4#16707217) on Android

**Procedure**

1. Connect Android device to the PC via USB
2. Enable USB tethering on the Android device (Settings)
3. Run the following script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   WAN="wlan1"       # interface providing internet connection on the PC
   LAN="usb0"        # usb interface on the PC
   AND="rndis0"      # usb interface on Android

   LAN_IP="10.0.0.1"
   AND_IP="10.0.0.10"
   NETMASK="255.255.255.0"

   DNS1="8.8.8.8"
   DNS2="8.8.4.4"

   sudo su -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
   sudo iptables -F -t nat
   sudo iptables -F FORWARD
   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -j MASQUERADE
   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $WAN -o $LAN -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $LAN -o $WAN -j ACCEPT

   sudo ifconfig $LAN $LAN_IP netmask $NETMASK up

   adb shell su -c busybox ifconfig $AND $AND_IP netmask $NETMASK up
   adb shell su -c busybox route add default gw $LAN_IP
   adb shell su -c ndc resolver setifdns $AND "" $DNS1 $DNS2
   adb shell su -c ndc resolver setdefaultif $AND

   adb shell ping -c4 $DNS1
   adb shell ping -c4 google.com
   ```
4. Done!

**Notes**

- You probably need to adjust the interface names `LAN`, `WAN` and `AND`.
- I found that some apps would either not recognize the network connection or only work partially. I was able to fool them using [Fake Wifi Connection](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.lemonsqueeze.fakewificonnection) module for the [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)