# Reverse USB Tethering of Android Marshmallow phone to allow sharing PC internet with my Android version 6 Phone

Tags: usb, internet, android, connection-sharing, tethering

## Problem

My Windows 10 PC has an Internet connection. My Android phone does not have Internet connection. Almost every suggestion on the internet is too old to work.

## Question

How can I share my PC's internet with an Android phone running Marshmallow (Android 6)?

---

#### Other posts that are *not* useful for answering this question

I was suggested other SuperUser posts to use. I've tried these and they no longer work for the following reasons:

[Access Internet on android phone by connecting it to laptop?](https://superuser.com/q/626683/109803) : Question is for Ubuntu and doesn't work on anything Lollipop and above

[Sharing a PC Internet to a Android phone via Bluetooth](https://superuser.com/q/782815/109803) : Too old to work for anything Lollipop and above, no longer maintained.

[Issue in internet sharing(ethernet) to android device in mavericks](https://superuser.com/q/808308/109803) : No answer and the person is asking about using their mac. I am trying to use a PC.

[Use PC internet on mobile phone via bluetooth](https://superuser.com/q/259075/109803) : Broken links renders the answer unusable.

Comment: Everyone who asks this question gets downvoted. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in the many duplicates? http://superuser.com/questions/626683/access-internet-on-android-phone-by-connecting-it-to-laptop http://superuser.com/questions/782815/sharing-a-pc-internet-to-a-android-phone-via-bluetooth?rq=1 http://superuser.com/questions/808308/issue-in-internet-sharingethernet-to-android-device-in-mavericks?rq=1

Comment: Yes I have, they are too old to work.

Comment: So what *have* you tried? What happened when you tried them? Did anything almost work? Have you found anything that might work but some step failed? **Share your research.** Saying things are "too old to work" doesn't help anyone to help you.

Comment: I'll have to try this when I get home, b/c I don't have admin privileges at work, but you can enable usb connection using RNDIS through developer options, then likely you need to mess around with network and sharing center on windows....

Comment: ah, I didn't know about this. I will try it now. I just saw this but I don't know enough about it to be able to try it: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/08/18/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices-that-support-windows-10-is-here

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to have windows 10 see the android device as a NDIS device?

Comment: @mokubai this question just crossed 1k views. Its because there isn't an answer to this question currently

Comment: @GabrielFair I'm not entirely sure why I should care that you got to 1k views.  All I wanted was you to explain ***what you had actually tried*** and ***how those things did or did not change your problem***.  Getting to 1k views with only 3 upvotes shows that while a lot of people may have browsed and found that you had a similar problem, very few of those people found your question helpful or useful enough to actually upvote it.

Comment: Use this free open source app. https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet

Comment: I have posted an exact solution for his issue on Android Enthusiasts, see: [Different ways of sharing internet connection from Windows to other devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159686/209414). If it works for you let me know so I can post a solution here too:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This free open source [project called (**gnirehtet**)](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) will allow you to do all kinds of theathering of your android phone to a **Mac**, **Linux** or **Windows** computer! The minimum version of android is 5.0 (marshmallow)

[image]